# jQuery getJSON reported undefined function error

Tags: jquery, undefined, getjson

I'm trying to load a json file when the page is loaded. So I tried this code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("./db/url.json", function(json) {
        console.log(json); 
    });
    console.log("The page is loaded"); 
});
```

resulted in this error:

```
 [Show/hide message details.] TypeError: $.getJSON is not a function[Learn More]
```

I read some similar posts, but I still can't figure it out. can you help?

The same result if I use `$.ajax`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you do not use the [slim](https://www.gadgetdaily.xyz/jquery-3-0-which-build-do-you-need-full-or-slim/) version (differences are in the link attached).
slim version does not include `.ajax` and `.getJSON`.

full version for jquery-3.1.1.min.js can be found [here](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js).

test it and check the result.

Comment: great, thanks! I am not aware of different of slim version.